# eclipse/java server faces- how to configure a facets project for jsf 2.1

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I am trying to create a JSF 2.1 Project in Eclipse Java EE IDE.

In one screen, Eclipse asks for JSF Implementation Libary- here I have defined JSF 2.1.10 as a JSF Implementation Library- with the JAR files

```
jsf-api-2.1.10.jar
```

and

```
jsf-impl-2.1.10.jar.
```

However after adding the above implementation library, I get the following error message in the same screen of Eclipse IDE--

```
 Required class javax.faces.FactoryFinder does not exist in selected libraries.
```

I even added Apache MyFaces Core 2.1.8 and  Mojarra 2.1.10, but the above error message refuses to go away... What am I missing here?

How do I configure and set up a JSF 2.1 project correctly in Eclipse Java EE IDE?

Thanks...

Comment: I suppose your question is same as described [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769880/does-the-eclipse-ide-support-jsf-2-0) Hope this helps.

Comment: can you check if inside **jsf-api-2.1.10.jar**, *FactoryFinder* is present ?

Answer (score 5):

**This is my solution:**

[image: Download Library with Eclipse]

***Eclipse Juno**

Comment: I cant see  these libraries on clicking Download Library

Answer (score 0):

You should click JaveServerfaces tag of your eclipse Project Facet when creating your project.See this

[image]