# What Eclipse IDE support JSF 2.0?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I downloaded the Eclipse Galileo and Juno Eclipse (Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers) but I can not run my JSF2 project. I've tried changing the Project Facets/JavaServer Faces for 2.0 but doesn´t allow the change. What Eclipse IDE support JSF 2.0?

Thanks!

Comment: The JBoss Tools is a good plugin to develop with JSF and more assets. It is available in the marketplace. Also, make sure you have downloaded the IDE for Java EE Developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Eclipse indigo. Its working fine for me.

Comment: I just download the Eclipse Indigo and has the option of JavaServer Faces 2.0 to create a New Dynamic Web Project. Thank you! I think now going to ok.

Answer (score 0):

For JSF 2.0, upgrade your Eclipse to version Helios (v3.6) onward, it has full support of Java EE 6 support, including JSF 2.0.

See: [Does the Eclipse IDE support JSF 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769880/does-the-eclipse-ide-support-jsf-2-0)

You can Google this answer relatively quickly.

Comment: Have I add some plugin? Because hasn´t the option New Dynamic Web Project.

Comment: have you installed the full j2ee edition? (i.e. Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers rather than Eclipse IDE for Java developers) - The EE is important!